# how to count how many times an arima order is not true before the first true order is obtained in r for different combo of arima simulation

Tags: r, if-statement, repeat, arima

Most times one runs `arima.sim()` function to simulate a particular order of `arima mosel` but when one check such simulated time series data through `auto.arima()` function, it will not often time be the same order of ARIMA one desire and specified in the `arima.sim()`.

In my bid to know how many times one may need to run `arima.sim()` function for a different combination of its parameter (sample size, standard deviation and coefficient of the model) before obtaining the true order of the model sought for, I want this `R` script to `count` how many time it will run an `arima.sim()` before it get the exert `ARIMA-order` specified in the `arima.sim()` function.

```
**Here is my trial**

library(forecast)
N <- c(10, 20, 30)
SD <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ^ 2
phi <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6)

## generate all combos
all_combos <- expand.grid(N = N, SD = SD, phi = phi)

## create function
set.seed(123)
res2 <- by(all_combos, all_combos["N"], function(DF){
  res <- mapply(function(N, SD, phi){
    cnt <- 0
    repeat {
      x <- arima.sim(n=N, model = list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = SD)
      if(all(arimaorder(auto.arima(x), ic = "aicc"))) != c(1, 0, 0) cnt <- cnt + 1){
      }
        {else(all(arimaorder(auto.arima(x), ic = "aicc"))) == c(1, 0, 0) cnt <- cnt + 1)}
        break
    }
    cnt
  }, DF[["N"]], DF[["SD"]], DF[["phi"]])
  names(res) <- paste("SD", DF[["SD"]], "phi", DF[["phi"]], sep = "-")
  res
})
res2
```

I am interested in knowing how many trials of `arima.sim()` will one make before obtaining the first ARIMA(1, 0, 0).

Comment: The algorithm is (1)set count to zero for each combo. (2) Count how many times the model order is not `(1, 0, 0)` before the first success of getting `(1, 0, 0)` for all combos. (3) Stop and do not include in the count when order `(1, 0, 0)` is obtained for all combos.

Comment: In which case my solution does not give you the desired result? If you run it enough times it gives you the number when you get `c(1, 0, 0)` combination.

Comment: I can not vote for any of the below as the correct answer for no value has been added since I put up the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

It seems odd to me that you are running `by` + `mapply`. I think only `mapply` is enough. Moreover, `arimaorder` does not have `ic` argument, maybe you meant to use it for `auto.arima` function.

Since you want to know how many trials are needed to get `c(1, 0, 0)`, I add an additional column (`index`) which is the row number in `all_combos`. As soon as you get output as `c(1, 0, 0)` the loop is broken and it prints the `index`.  The code doesn't run for rest of the combinations.

```
library(forecast)
N <- c(10, 20, 30)
SD <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ^ 2
phi <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6)

## generate all combos
all_combos <- expand.grid(N = N, SD = SD, phi = phi)
all_combos$index <- seq_len(nrow(all_combos))

mapply(function(N, phi, SD, index) {
  x <- with(all_combos, arima.sim(n=N[1], 
             model = list(ar=phi[1], order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = SD[1]))
  if(all(arimaorder(auto.arima(x, ic = "aicc")) == c(1, 0, 0))) {
    print(index)
    break
  }
}, all_combos$N, all_combos$SD, all_combos$phi, all_combos$index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your curly braces are in the wrong spots. I get errors about unexpected braces when I run your code. The `R` notation for `if` and `else` should follow:

```
if(condition == TRUE) {
run some code
} else {                    
do some other code       # happens if condition == FALSE
}
```

If you want to check a different condition, you need `else if`

```
if(condition == TRUE) {
run some code
} else if(other_condition == TRUE) {                    
do some other code       
} else {
do some third code      # runs if both conditions are FALSE
}
```

You also have your parentheses for `all()` misplaced. Based on this, I think you want your conditionals to look like:

```
if(all(arimaorder(auto.arima(x), ic = "aicc")) != c(1, 0, 0)) {
   cnt <- cnt + 1
   } else if (all(arimaorder(auto.arima(x), ic = "aicc")) == c(1, 0, 0)) {
       cnt <- cnt + 1
       } else { break }
```

When I fix these, the code almost runs, except I get the error

Error in arimaorder(auto.arima(x), ic = "aicc") :
unused argument (ic = "aicc")

So, your parentheses for `auto.arima()` were also misplaced. The following runs without error:

```
res2 <- by(all_combos, all_combos["N"], function(DF){
   res <- mapply(function(N, SD, phi){
      cnt <- 0
      repeat {
         x <- arima.sim(n=N, model = list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = SD)
         if(all(arimaorder(auto.arima(x, ic = "aicc"))) != c(1, 0, 0)) {
      cnt <- cnt + 1
   } else if (all(arimaorder(auto.arima(x, ic = "aicc"))) == c(1, 0, 0)) {
   cnt <- cnt + 1
} else { break }
      }
      cnt
   }, DF[["N"]], DF[["SD"]], DF[["phi"]])
names(res) <- paste("SD", DF[["SD"]], "phi", DF[["phi"]], sep = "-")
res
})
```

However, I still think there is a problem in these lines, and I can't figure out what you were trying to accomplish.

```
      cnt
   }, DF[["N"]], DF[["SD"]], DF[["phi"]])
```

Comment: it runs indefinately

Comment: @DanielJames - Yes. It means that the `break` conditions are never met. Either the `if` statement or the `else if` statement is always true.